# YTM and current yield

Tags: bond

Which of the following statements is correct?

a. If a bond’s yield to maturity exceeds its coupon rate, the bond’s current yield must also exceed its coupon rate.

b. If a bond’s yield to maturity exceeds its coupon rate, the bond’s price must be less than its maturity value.

The correct answer is b. I would like to know why option a is incorrect.

If bond price is less than maturity value, then current yield = (annual coupon payment)/(current bond price) > coupon rate. Is there anything wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: Where does that come from? CFA exercises?

Comment: It comes from the book 'Essentials of Financial Management'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a) is false**

Consider a zero coupon bond.  Yield to maturity clearly exceeds the coupon rate, but

$$
Y_\text{current} = 0 = \text{Coupon}
$$

while the question asks about a strict inequality.

Comment: Wow ! Nice one.

Comment: The answer would be more complete if you restated the definitions of the 3.

Answer (score 0):

No you're right. If YTM > coupon rate, then the bond is selling below par and therefore current yield > coupon rate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a straight, option-free bond, then A is absolutely correct.  It's rather easy to prove doing the math.  However, if it's not a straight bond then you may have cases where A wouldn't be true(puttable bonds in some cases), but then B would be false in those cases as well.  I think you need to burn whatever book you're reading.